# How can I initialize array from another class in my current class constructor in c++?

Tags: arrays, pointers, c++11, visual-c++

I have class "Student" and "Course" class.
My "Student" class contains inside it- Course** courseList - pointers array.
Now, when i'm realization my "Student" constructor how can i initialize my courseList array? can i do it at all despite the fact the array is a type that belongs to another class?

Comment: Two things. 1. Types don't belong to classes. I think you mean that the array is a member of another class. 2. What class is array a member of?

Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if you are talking about like:

```
class Course
{
   ...
}

class Student
{
    Course ** courseList;
    public:
        Student();
    ...
 }


Student::Student()
{
    int numberofCourses = 10;
    courseList = new (Course*)[numberofCourses];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofCourses ; i++)
        courseList[i] = new Course();
}
```

Just showing the idea, the actual codes may vary.